# HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request - Swift - Post API

Tags: json, swift, api

I'm making a POST function but I'm getting an error. I am getting

> HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request

error in console. In the simulator, it says

> Something went wrong. Please try again later

on the screen. I don't understand where I am making the mistake.

JSON Model:

```
struct TaniTalep: Encodable {

    let photo: Data?
    let xray: Data?
    let talep: String
   
    init(photo: UIImage?, xray: UIImage?, talep: Talep) throws {

        self.photo = photo?.pngData()
        self.xray = xray?.pngData()

        let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(talep)

        self.talep = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}

struct Talep: Codable {

    let tanitalepid: Int
    let hastaid: Int
    let cevap: String
    let anamnezList: [Anamnez]
    let sikayetanaList: [SikayetAna]
    let sorucevapList: [SoruCevap]

    struct SoruCevap: Codable {

        let sikayetsoruid: Int
        let soru: String
        let sorucevap: String
    }

    struct SikayetAna: Codable {

        let sikayet: String
        let sikayetanaid: Int
    }

    struct Anamnez: Codable {

        let aciklama: String
        let anamnezid: Int
        let cevap: String
        let nitelik: String
        let sonaltiay: String
    }
}
```

Web Service:

```
func postTaniTalep(token: String, email: String, tanitalepid: Int, taniTalep: TaniTalep) async throws -> Bool {

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://ec2-3-74-42-117.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/dentistodayapis/inserttanitalep") else {

            throw NetworkError.invalidURL
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
//        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.addValue("\(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "credentialtoken")
        request.addValue("\(email)", forHTTPHeaderField: "username")
        request.addValue("IOS", forHTTPHeaderField: "platform")
        request.addValue("TR", forHTTPHeaderField: "langcode")

        let formData = try JSONEncoder().encode(taniTalep)

        print("\(Date())-\(#line)--\(#function)--formData: \(String(data: formData, encoding: .utf8))-")

        request.httpBody = formData

        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)

        print(url)
        print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))

        return (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200

    }
```

View:

```
final class TaniTalepViewModel: ObservableObject {

    static let shared = TaniTalepViewModel()

    init() {}

    

    var hastaID: Int?
    var cevap: String?
    var soruCevapList = [Talep.SoruCevap]()
    var sikayetAnaList = [Talep.SikayetAna]()
    var anamnezList = [Talep.Anamnez]()
    var photo: UIImage?
    var xray: UIImage?

    @Published var message: String?

    @MainActor

    func postTaniTalep() async {

        guard

            let hastaID = hastaID,

            let cevap = cevap

        else {

            assertionFailure("Insufficient data")

            return

        }

        

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        guard let token = defaults.string(forKey: "jsonwebtoken") else {

            return

        }

        guard let email = defaults.string(forKey: "email") else {

            return

        }

        do {

            let tanitalepid = try await Webservice().getSequenceNextval(token: token, email: email)

            let success = try await Webservice().postTaniTalep(token: token, email: email, tanitalepid: tanitalepid, taniTalep: TaniTalep(photo: photo, xray: xray, talep: .init(tanitalepid: tanitalepid, hastaid: hastaID, cevap: cevap, anamnezList: anamnezList, sikayetanaList: sikayetAnaList, sorucevapList: soruCevapList)))

            if success {

                message = "Your registration number \(tanitalepid) has been completed successfully.\n \(tanitalepid) numaralı kaydınız başarıyla tamamlanmıştır."

            } else {

                message = "Something went wrong. Please try again later."
            }
        } catch {

            print("\(Date())-\(#line)--\(#function)--error: \(error)-")

            message = "Error while posting tani talep: \(error)"
        }
    }
}

struct TaniTalepView: View {

    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = TaniTalepViewModel.shared

    
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            Color.flesh
                .ignoresSafeArea()

            if let message = viewModel.message {
                Text(message)
                    .padding()
            } else {
                ProgressView()
            }
        }
        .task {
            await viewModel.postTaniTalep()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using `http` instead of the required `https`. Have you setup your `NSAppTransportSecurity`  in your `Info.plist` to allow `http` connection to the server?

Comment: yes other POST and GET functions work fine

Comment: It is a typical issue. My thoughts are: it would be helpful to contact your colleague who did the endpoint to provide you with Postman's requests, so you could clearly see all the parameters and formats. Then you could also use Proxyman to track what data is really being sent from your side (from iOS simulator). Other than that - only guessing. Guessing, what data format should be sent.